# How can I autocomplete the name of a file in Linux when passing the remote flag to firefox?

Tags: linux, firefox

I am attempting to open a file using firefox via the command line. The command I run is;

```
firefox -remote "openurl(file://`pwd`/filename.html)"
```

I would like to be able to autocomplete the name of the file which can sometimes be lengthy by hitting tab.

Comment: The reason that it doesn't work are the double quotes!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it’s clunky, but you could type

> `` sh -c 'firefox -remote "openurl(file://`pwd`/$1)"'  -  Pea ``<kbd>Tab</kbd>

or

> `` sh -c 'firefox -remote "openurl(file://$1/$2)"'  -  `pwd`  Pea ``<kbd>Tab</kbd>

If you’re going to be doing this on a regular basis (without a lot of variation), you might want to put it into a script.

P.S. You could leave off one of the slashes after the `file:` because the `pwd` will provide one.

---

Edit:

#### How/why does this work?

The interactive shell that you’re running (let’s assume that it is `bash` and refer to it as such, for disambiguation) is the one that’s reading your command line input and doing things like autocomplete, and it requires that any command-line word that it autocompletes must look like a filename or pathname.  I’ve had the experience that it can handle

> … `$PWD/Sco`<kbd>Tab</kbd>

and

> … `` `pwd`/Sco ``<kbd>Tab</kbd>

but not

> … `$(pwd)/Sco`<kbd>Tab</kbd>

Go figure.  YMMV.  In any case, it cannot handle

> … `` "openurl(file://`pwd`/Sco ``<kbd>Tab</kbd>

because that cannot possibly be interpreted as a filename or pathname
(unless `bash` could parse the `"openurl(…`  call, which it cannot).

The trick is to get it to do the autocomplete on an isolated filename and then glue the pieces together.  The only way to set `$1`, `$2`, etc., for your interactive shell is to type a command like `set foo bar` or `set -- foo bar`, and this is generally not done.  We need a `sh` on the command line so we can set its `$1`, `$2`, etc., by putting values on its command line. 
So we use the `bash` to do the autocomplete, which provides command-line parameter(s) to `sh`,
and then we use the `sh` command

> `'firefox -remote "openurl(file://$1/$2)"'`

to interpret the `$1` and `$2`, and then “glue the pieces together”.

---

The process of writing this made me realize another option:

> `` set  `pwd`  Sco ``<kbd>Tab</kbd>*(do autocomplete)* <kbd>Enter</kbd>

followed by

> `firefox -remote "openurl(file:/$1/$2)"` <kbd>Enter</kbd>

As I indicated earlier, the first command above sets the positional parameters (`$1` and `$2`) for the interactive shell (`bash`) and the second line uses them. 
As I mentioned, people generally don’t set the positional parameters of their interactive shell,
but there’s nothing wrong with it –– it’s just uncommon. 
It should be noted that `$1` and `$2` will retain these values until you reset them, or you logout.

You should be able to combine the above two lines into one:

> `` set `pwd` Sco ``<kbd>Tab</kbd>*(do autocomplete)* **`;`**  
>  `firefox -remote "openurl(file:/$1/$2)"` <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Comment: Why do I need to run the `sh` command?

Comment: Because the interactive shell that you’re running (let’s assume that it is `bash` and refer to it as such, for disambiguation) is the one that’s reading your command line input and doing things like autocomplete, and it requires that any command-line word that it autocompletes must look like a filename or pathname.  I don’t know off-hand whether it can handle `\`pwd\`/Pea`(Tab), but, as you have discovered, it certainly cannot handle `"openurl(file://\`pwd\`/Pea`(Tab).

Comment: The trick is to get it to do the autocomplete on an isolated filename and then glue the pieces together.  The only way to set `$1`, `$2`, etc., for your interactive shell is to type a command like `set foo bar` or `set -- foo bar`.  We need a `sh` on the command line so we can set its `$1`, `$2`, etc., by putting values on its command line.  So we use the `bash` to do the autocomplete, which provides a command-line parameter to `sh`, and then we use the `sh` command `'firefox -remote "openurl(file://$1/$2)"'` to interpret the `$1` and `$2`, and then “glue the pieces together”.

Comment: @PeanutsMonkey: I updated my answer.